# How to get specific element from foreach (data from database (PDO))

Tags: php, html, css

I am using `foreach` to write down all elements from my PDO result (I am making a question on DB which returns me some `data --> lot of data`). I am writing down all of them to table (basically it has to looks like admin interface, if you need to imagine it, it's something when you in CMS are admin and want to see all posts or articles).

The problem is when I want to choose some line from that table (example: I want to pick article `New age of cellphones`, which is on line `41`) and open this article (there will be some options as edit, delete, etc)it choose the FIRST element (first written `article -> lowest ID`). Can you help me out?

```
foreach($resultedArticle as $data){
    $short_content = substr($data["Content"], 0, 30);
    $short_description = substr($data["Description"], 0, 30);
    echo "                      
        <tr>
            <td>". $data['ID'] ."</td>
            <td>". $data['Name'] ."</td>
            <td>". strip_tags($short_description) ."...</td>
            <td>". strip_tags($short_content) ."...</td>
            <td>". $data['Type']. "</td>
            <td>". $data['Created'] ." </td>
            <td>". $data['Modified'] ."</td>
            <td>". $data['Status'] . "</td>
            <td> <a href='#modal1' class='modal-trigger' title='Zobrazit detaily zápisu'><i class='material-icons'>fullscreen</i></a></td>
            <td> <a href='#modal_edit' title='Editovat zápis'><i class='material-icons'>mode_edit</i></a></td>
            <td> <a href='../../core.php?action=deleteArticle&ID=". $data['ID'] ."' title='Smazat zápis'><i class='material-icons'>clear</i></a></td>
        </tr>
        <div id='modal_edit' class='modal modal-fixed-footer'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                      <h4>Edit your article</h4>

                            <div class='row'>
                                  <form class='col s12' method='POST' action='../../core.php?action=editArticle'>
                                      <div class='row'>
                                        <div class='input-field col s6'>
                                          <input name='name' id='name' type='text' class='validate' placeholder='". $data["Name"] ."'/>
                                          <label for='name'>Název</label>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class='row'> 
                                        <div class='input-field col s6'>
                                          <input name='description' id='description' type='text' class='validate' placeholder='". $data["Description"] ."'/>
                                          <label for='description'>Popisek</label>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class='row'>
                                        <input id='ID' name='ID' type='hidden' value='". $data["ID"] ."'/>
                                        <button id='submit' class='btn waves-effect waves-light right' type='submit' name='action'> Upravit projekt </button>
                                      </div>
                                  </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='modal-footer'>
                            <a href='#!'' class='modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ''>Zrušit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        ";
```

EDIT: You can notice I am creating also modal window (form) in the same foreach isn't problem there?

Comment: `id` should be unique for every modal

Comment: oh so I have to generate the modal with specific class or id and then calls specific modal window right?

Comment: your modal code should'nt be in a loop, you can keep it in a once, and same can be opened on click of the your action button like edit or fullscreen using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code i have added `ID` to every modal
basically this is not proper method of using modal, instead of you can create only one model outside of loop and fill all the data with jQuery or javascript, for now it will work

```
foreach($resultedArticle as $data){

    $modal_id = "#modal_edit_$data['ID']";         

    $short_content = substr($data["Content"], 0, 30);
    $short_description = substr($data["Description"], 0, 30);
    echo "                      
        <tr>
            <td>". $data['ID'] ."</td>
            <td>". $data['Name'] ."</td>
            <td>". strip_tags($short_description) ."...</td>
            <td>". strip_tags($short_content) ."...</td>
            <td>". $data['Type']. "</td>
            <td>". $data['Created'] ." </td>
            <td>". $data['Modified'] ."</td>
            <td>". $data['Status'] . "</td>
            <td> <a href='#modal1' class='modal-trigger' title='Zobrazit detaily zápisu'><i class='material-icons'>fullscreen</i></a></td>
            <td> <a href='".$modal_id."' title='Editovat zápis'><i class='material-icons'>mode_edit</i></a></td>
            <td> <a href='../../core.php?action=deleteArticle&ID=". $data['ID'] ."' title='Smazat zápis'><i class='material-icons'>clear</i></a></td>
        </tr>
        <div id='" .$modal_id. "' class='modal modal-fixed-footer'>
            <div class='modal-content'>
                <h4>Edit your article</h4>
                <div class='row'>
                    <form class='col s12' method='POST' action='../../core.php?action=editArticle'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='input-field col s6'>
                                <input name='name' id='name' type='text' class='validate' placeholder='". $data["Name"] ."'/>
                                <label for='name'>Název</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row'> 
                            <div class='input-field col s6'>
                                <input name='description' id='description' type='text' class='validate' placeholder='". $data["Description"] ."'/>
                                <label for='description'>Popisek</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <input id='ID' name='ID' type='hidden' value='". $data["ID"] ."'/>
                            <button id='submit' class='btn waves-effect waves-light right' type='submit' name='action'> Upravit projekt </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
                <a href='#!'' class='modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ''>Zrušit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    ";
```

Comment: No sorry, it's not even opening the modal window now but the solution with id="modal_edit_$data['ID']" is really cool!

Comment: true i have updated my code and accept answer if it helps you

Comment: again great idea but the modal window isn't opening... Without this dynamic ID it's opening, I am calling it via class="modal" which is not beeing changed, hmmm